# getting xml file from a website and copying it to a server

Tags: xml, linux

My question is very broad since I do not know exactly what I ought to do. It will be my first trial. I hope I can express my need adequately.

I want to read and than copy an xml file from a website and copy it to my amazon cloud server account. I want to write the code on my amazon server on linux platform.

1- I need to check the xml file on the website every day.

2- If there is a change in the xml file, I will get it and copy it to my amazon cloud server. 
(perhaps I can compare character lengths of today's and previous day's xml file in order to understand if there is a change)

3-I made a research and I found wget command can be used to copy a file.

Could you please give me some sample codes and guideline?

Many thanks,

I apologize if my question is nonsense or ambiguous .

Comment: When posting questions on SO you must give some evidence that you have tried to solve the problem.  People on SO do not react well to "Please give me the sample code".  You are expected to work on the solution and ask a specific question about something that is not working the way you expect.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: You are right Jim, I appreciate your answer however, I have no experience in that field. I know nothing about linux. I accept that my question is bad. However, I need to do that, earlier or later I will succeed.

Comment: 1. Break the job down into separate, small tasks. 2. Pick a programming language. 3. Try to solve each task in turn, and look for help when you get stuck.

Comment: There's nothing Linux specific about this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use the `wget` or `curl` commands to download the XML file. You can use `diff` to compare the new file to the old file. Maybe look into creating a `bash` shell script to automate these processes, and schedule it to run periodically with `cron`. I think you could have this run directly on your "cloud server", rather than transfer the XML file there after doing these checks.